# ReactJS: ';' expected while mapping over an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create an array of objects in the following manner:

```
function allNewDice(){
    const newDice = new Array(10).fill(0).map(x => {
        value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6), 
        isOn : false }
    )}
```

However next to isOn property, I am getting the error  **';' expected**
What am I doing wrong

If I use a for loop to create the same, it works. However mapping is not working

Comment: `const newDice = new Array(10).fill(0).map(x => ({
        value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6), 
        isOn : false }
    ))`

Comment: You need to fix your parentheses and braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with the arrow function syntax. To return an object, you need to wrap it in parentheses.

```
function allNewDice(){
        const newDice = new Array(10).fill(0).map(x => ({
            value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6), 
            isOn : false })
        )}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function allNewDice() {
  const newDice = new Array(10).fill(0).map(x => {
    return {
      value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6),
      isOn: false
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function allNewDice() {
    const newDice = new Array(10).fill(0).map((x) => ({
        value: Math.ceil(Math.random() * 6),
        isOn: false,
    }));
}
```